# "Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found." on query for one property

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to use google firestore in a node.js application.  I started with a simple user authentication, looking for users with a given ID:

```
const query = datastore.createQuery('users').filter('googleId', '=', googleId)

const [result] = await datastore.runQuery(query)
```

This line always throws an exception with

```
Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found.
```

Despite the documentation, it does not suggest how to resolve this issue.

This query works in the datastore emulator, but the emulator then suggests no indices.

When I try to add an index on this property in the cloud console, the console insists that it already exists as a default index, which is clearly not the case.

How do I query a simple property in Cloud Datastore?

Comment: This is quite strange. I used this on my testing project and is working well. Maybe you should try on new fresh project...?

Comment: Is your database in Firestore native or Datastore mode.  If it is in native mode you'll need to use the Firestore client libraries instead of the Datastore libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Jim in the comments, the problem is that my database was in Firestore mode while I was using the Datastore client library.  Despite what the documentation says, these are not compatible.